# Update a cck field value of a node

Tags: 6

I have a cck field in a node. I bring this value out in some other form and alter its value, But i am unable to save it back to DB. How should i write it back to table such that node changed date also gets changed. please show some code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/6) to do this; CCK will automatically hook into it and update the field values in the database for you:

```
// Load a node
$node = node_load(1);

// Update the field value
$node->field_field_name = array(0 => array('value' => 'A value'));

// Save the node. Field values are also saved, and the node modified time is updated.
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)(&$node, $op, ...) with `$op='presave'`.